# Prevent added line breaks after GO from SSMS script to.... function

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I often generate a script of all of my stored procs for doing full searches of the scripts.

When I have SSMS generate create scripts for sp's, it adds extra line breaks that I have to remove after the ANSI_NULLS/QUOTED_IDENTIFIER lines at the top. If I use that script without removing those lines and make it an alter, those extra lines compound, creating extras next time.

Is there any way to customise that script generation to prevent the line addition?

[image: Extra lines added after GO]

Comment: Pretty sure you have no control over that.

Comment: `I often generate a script of all of my stored procs for doing full searches of the script` i hope you know that you can do this by doing `select object_name(object_id), definition from sys.sql_modules`

Comment: Why does it matter that there's whitespace there?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that your database schema should be being source controlled as scripts or using a more structured solution, such that you're not having to retrieve these definitions from the database to start with.

Comment: The way you're describing the compounding effect, it sounds like you're re-injecting the generated script back into the database? If so, you're using the scripts for more than just "full searches".

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I've found doing a Find and Replace with regex (Alt+E in find/replace) does the same:
Find: GO\x0d\x0a
Replace: GO